# Dynamically set width and height of TextView in Android

Tags: height, width, textview, android

I am trying to set TextView width dynamically, Using `setWidth(width)` method.

```
txtviewOne.setWidth(10);
txtviewTwo.setWidth(10);
```

But not success.

Please help me How can I set width of textview dynamically.

Comment: TextView I used in AbsoluteLayout    <AbsoluteLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

Answer (score 11):

```
TextView tv;
----------------------
tv=new TextView(this);   // or  tv=new TextView(R.id.textview1);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(15,50);
tv.setLayoutParams(Params1);
```

Comment: Can you certainly use the **resId** to create a  TextView instance?

Answer (score 5):

I call `new TableRow()`, because textView's parent is `TableRow`. If your parent's view is `LinearLayout`, replace it by `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

```
textView.setLayoutParams(
    new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced something similar in situations where there is a ScrollView in the parents hierarchy. No matter how I would modify layout inside it, my commands were ignored. If this is the case, try calling RequestLayout on the ScrollView or remove and re-add the child view of the ScrollView.