# set width to the textview doesn't work

Tags: android, view

I want to set the width of my text-view in code to `width =119`

```
tv.setWidth(width);
int width2 = tv.getWidth();
```

but I get the result

```
width2 =12
```

I have this code in the onlayout method and when onlayout called again (I think when the text-view is actually on screen )by the android system the result will be correct

```
width2 =119
```

I think if the width is set to fixed value you can set it again to the another value before it is drawn in the UI.

How can I know when onlayout will be called because sometimes it doesn't called again I mean after the textview is actually on screen?

Comment: I think that your view has a parent which limite its size

Comment: Why do you want to set a width instead of using a layout file to position and set its size automatically?

Comment: have you tried as `tv.getLayoutParams().height = 119;` ?

Comment: because I want to calculate the width depending on the width of screen

Comment: I have answered a similar question. Might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26233453/517450

Answer (score 7):

You have to try set the width with `LayoutParams` option like this :

```
TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(119,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: notice: I am making the TextView tv = new TextView(getContext()); in onFinishInflate and setting the params in onLayout method

Comment: Why exist setWidth ?!

Answer (score 6):

```
LayoutParams param = txtv.getLayoutParams();
param.width = 45;
txtv.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(15,50);
tv.setLayoutParams(Params1);
```

Comment: Perhaps explaining why this could be the asnwer can help the OP.

Comment: TextView.setWidth calls requestLayout() and invalidate(). This apparently in certain situations, such as when the parent layout's dimensions are still not determined or are dependent on the children to be added, resets the width back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

All UI-Manipulations like setHeight, setLayoutParams, setText etc. will NOT block until everything is rendered on screen. So when you call setHeight it will return immediately to your code while some kind of a notice is placed for the UI to be altered on the next rendering cycle.

So when you do your getHeight the ui had not been re-rendered thus giving the old height the element still has.

You can delay your getHeight code to the next time the ui is ready for a new rendering by using view.post(). As the setHeight was done before view.post() will only run after setHeight had been rendered:

```
tv.setWidth(width);
tv.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() //code here is only executed after setWidth has been rendered
    {
        Log.d(TAG," tv has been set to height="+ tv.getWidth();
    }
});
```